# Ansible - Convert list of strings to a list of dictionaires with predefined key

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to install packages on a new deployment. I have a pre-defined list of dicts in a variable.

I want to open an *interface* to update this list using Jenkins.

My list looks like this:

```
package_list: [
  {'name': 'python-devel', 'apt': 'python-dev'},
  {'name': 'python-pip'},
  {'name': 'postgresql-devel'},
  ...
  ]
```

The way I communicate Jenkins input to Ansible is using *environment variables*. I can pass a list of *additional packages* to be installed and read it as part of my Ansible configuration.

Question is: **How I convert a list of strings, to a list of dictionaries matches the structure of my package_list?**

For example:

```
ENV:
PACKAGES=gcc,vim,ntp

ANSIBLE:
additional_packages = [
    {'name': 'gcc'},
    {'name': 'vim'},
    {'name': 'ntp'}
]
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe this playbook will get you where you want. it assumes you have the env variable: `PACKAGES=gcc,vim,ntp`

it converts the string variable to a list (split by `,`), and then in another loop it converts to a list of dictionaries:

playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
    - name: pick up env variable, convert to list
      set_fact:
         PACKAGES: "{{ lookup('env', 'PACKAGES').split(',') }}"

    - name: create dict list variable
      set_fact:
         PACKAGES_DICT: "{{ PACKAGES_DICT|default([]) + [{'name': item}] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ PACKAGES }}"

    - name: print results
      debug:
        var: PACKAGES_DICT
```

results:

```
TASK [print results] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "PACKAGES_DICT": [
        {
            "name": "gcc"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "vim"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "ntp"
        }
    ]
}
```

hope this helps

**EDIT**

refining the code, removing the `set_fact` task, declaring the PACKAGES variable in `vars` section:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    PACKAGES: "{{ lookup('env', 'PACKAGES').split(',') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: create dict list variable
      set_fact:
         PACKAGES_DICT: "{{ PACKAGES_DICT|default([]) + [{'name': item}] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ PACKAGES }}"

    - name: print results
      debug:
        var: PACKAGES_DICT
```

Comment: thanks! this does what I need, but I prefer to put it in a `role/defaults/main.yml` where the rest of my variables are. Is it possible to make it work inside `main.yml`? Or I need to create a task for that?

Comment: this playbook was like a demo, if you want to do things a bit more efficiently you could set the `PACKAGES: "{{ lookup('env', 'PACKAGES').split(',') }}"` directly in the vars section, please see updated answer. So, this declaration could be put in the `role/defaults/main.yml`, but the second part where we create the dict list variable has to be via a task, i guess you cant have that in the `role/defaults/main.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep looking for a way, if I don't find any I would accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

For people who come here and are looking for an "inline" solution without tasks (e. g. inside a YAML file for variables):

```yaml
packages: "{{ lookup('env', 'PACKAGES').split(',') }}"
additional_packages: "{{ packages | map('community.general.dict_kv', 'name') }}"
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Ansible, list should be written that way:

```
package_list:
  - name: "gcc"
  - name: "vim"
  - name: "ntp
```

so to get that list from the string you can do that way:

```
vars:
  package_list: "{{ packages.split(',').values() | list }}"
```

Comment: This solution does the opposite to what OP requested, i.e. converts from a dictionary to a list.